# How to add one loop arrays value to another loop

Tags: bash, macos, shell, terminal

I have a script which finds all the Cert. identity on the system then I want to add one more Cert. and delete rest of Cert except which is added recently.

1st loop finds how many identity we have in the system and set array as `$var1 $var2 $var3` and no. continues.

Then I add one more.

Now  I want to delete 1 loop array values herein for loop. But my $DEL variable is coming as var1 var2, not the actual identity we have set in 1st loop.

```
#!/bin/bash

DOM=$(/usr/sbin/dsconfigad -show | grep "Active Directory Domain" | awk '{ print $5 }')
MAC=$(/usr/sbin/dsconfigad -show | grep "Computer Account" | awk '{ print $4 }' | tr -d "$")
HOST=$MAC.$DOM
CRT=$(security find-identity -v | grep $HOST | awk '{ print $2}')



set - $CRT; index=0; while [ "$1" ]; 
do 
 let index=$index+1; 
 eval var${index}="$1"; 
 shift;
done
```

The above loop result is: `+ set - 02KFKDSF89SFMDFMFS7908934M90DODFSMN78345 K69SKLD04KCM62469933FA60567LLFD730957FA3 489FHDFS93MDF89UY2345905DFSKDDSKFDS9FSEF`

```
echo $var1
echo $var2
```

The echo $var1 is: `02KFKDSF89SFMDFMFS7908934M90DODFSMN78345`

The echo $var2 is: `K69SKLD04KCM62469933FA60567LLFD730957FA3`

```
NUMCRT=$index
echo "Number of Certificate is $NUMCRT"
echo "Add of Script part bla bla Start"
echo "ADD one more Cert"
echo "Add of Script part bla bla END"
```

Now I want to delete array value which I have found in the 1st loop. But `$DEL` value is coming `var1` `var2` `var3` and not  `02KFKDSF89SFMDFMFS7908934M90DODFSMN78345` `K69SKLD04KCM62469933FA60567LLFD730957FA3` `489FHDFS93MDF89UY2345905DFSKDDSKFDS9FSEF`.

```
for i in $(seq 1 $NUMCRT); 
do 
 let $i;
 DEL="var$i"
 echo "Delete number $DEL"
done
```

It should show `echo "Delete number $DEL"` in 2nd `for` loop value as below.

```
Delete number 02KFKDSF89SFMDFMFS7908934M90DODFSMN78345
Delete number K69SKLD04KCM62469933FA60567LLFD730957FA3
Delete number 489FHDFS93MDF89UY2345905DFSKDDSKFDS9FSEF
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to run dsconfigad twice.

```
domain=''; machine='';
while IFS="=" read key val
do case "$key" in
   "Active Directory Domain"*) domain=$( echo $val )  ;; # strip space
          "Computer Account"*) machine=$( echo $val ) ;; # strip space
                            *) if [[ -n "$domain"  ]] &&
                                  [[ -n "$machine" ]] 
                               then break
                               fi;;
   esac
done < <( /usr/sbin/dsconfigad -show )
```

I can't find a good example of `security find-identity -v` including the verbose option, so I'm going to fake my way through this by using your command structure, though I'm still not going to use all-caps vars (don't do that).

```
 declare -a crt=( $( security find-identity -v | grep $machine.$domain | awk '{ print $2}' ) )
```

Now the values are in the `$crt[@]` array, numerically indexed.
If you know the index of the one you want to remove,

```
unset "crt[$num]"
```

This does leave a hole in your array...
Alternately, use the values themselves as the keys, and you won't have to track the indexes and leave holes in your array.

```
 declare -A crt=()
 while read one
 do crt[$one]=1
 done < <( security find-identity -v | grep $HOST | awk '{ print $2}' ) )
```

Now you can remove it with

```
unset "crt[$val]" # assuming $val is the key
```

or walk through them with

```
for val in "${!crt[@]}"
do : something with the key...
done
```

Useful?
As always, folks please check me. I don't have either of these tools installed. Working blind and likely screwing something up. :)